# ack|grep|whatnot special ignore folders pattern node_modules/dir/node_modules

Tags: node.js, grep, node-modules, ack

I have recently discovered ack and `ack -ir --ignore-dir={node_modules,dist,.git} <search-term>` works great for most things but this

```
---node_modules/
---------------project1/
-----------------------node_modules/
---------------project2/
-----------------------node_modules/
```

I would like to search all files under the "root" node_modules and excluding all internal ones.

Note: if I run `find . -type f | ack -v 'node_modules|.git|dist'` under the root node_modules folder, I get a proper file list. this happen because `find .` gives out relative paths. Any way to feed this list to ack ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
ack -i <search-term> ./node_modules/*
```

should do what you want.
If you want to include *hidden* files and folders too, set `shopt -s dotglob` (assumes Bash) first.

---

**Background information:**

`ack` has many rules for ignoring files that you don't typically want to be searched *built in*.

As of at least version 2.14, this *includes* directories named `.git` and `node_modules`, at whatever level of the hierarchy (`ack` searches recursively by default, though you may add `-r` / `-R` / `--recursive` to make that explicit).
To see the complete list of directories / files that are ignored by default, run `ack --dump`.

By using *globbing* (pathname expansion) to let the *shell* expand pattern `./node_modules/*` to a *list* of actual items *inside* `./node_modules`, the ignore rule for `node_modules` is *bypassed* for those explicitly passed items.

Answer (score 6):

`node_modules` is in the default `--ignore-dir` list in `ack` for javascript.

You can disable this using the `--noignore-dir` option to un-ignore node_modules.

- directly on the command line:

  ```
  % ack --noignore-dir=node_modules -i <search-term>
  ```
- in your `.ackrc` file:

  ```
  # in .ackrc
  --noignore-dir=node_modules
  ```

  which affects all searches:

  ```
  % ack -i <search-term>
  ```

Comment: I'm kind of answering the wrong question, but I'm'ma leave it here so I find this later....

Comment: If you want to specifically search in that directory, you can specify it, and then ack won't ignore it, like so:  `ack somestring node_modules`